# How to persist CGPaths to CoreData

Tags: ios, swift, core-graphics

I am making a drawing app on iOS and would like to save a users drawing to core data.

I know NSData is an attribute type for CoreData so I was thinking of using that maybe.

My idea is to somehow convert my array of CGPaths to NSData and then save the NSData to Core Data. Does anyone have insight in to how I would do this or a better solution out there?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you convert your `CGPath` to a `UIBezierPath`, that supports `NSCoding`/`NSSecureCoding`:

```
do {
    let path = UIBezierPath(cgPath: cgPath)
    let data = try NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: path, requiringSecureCoding: false)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

You can also convert `Data` back to `UIBezierPath`:

```
do {
    if let path = try NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchivedObject(ofClass: UIBezierPath.self, from: data) {
        let cgPath = path.cgPath
    }
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Also do you think this is an efficient way of storing a drawing composed of CGPaths?

Comment: I generally work directly with `UIBezierPath` rather than `CGPath` (which eliminates a step in the above process). I’d also consider capturing the actual model information (coordinates) rather than storing relatively opaque CoreGraphics/UIKit objects as blobs. Regarding efficiency, you should benchmark it and see if there’s a material difference. SQLite is notoriously inefficient at handling very large objects, but you are likely dealing with blobs that are small enough that this is likely irrelevant. But just benchmark it and see. This is beyond the scope of the above question, regardless.

Answer (score 0):

Since `UIBezierPath` conforms to `NSSecureCoding` all you have to do is set he custom class and the module to make it work.

```
entity.path = UIBezierPath(cgPath: cgPath)
```

[image]